# Why does flowtype complain when I try to implement an interface?

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

In defining a `libdef`, I have:

```
declare class Resource implements ResourceOptions {
        app ? : Express | Router;
        sequelize ? : Sequelize;
        model: any;
        endpoints ? : string[];
        actions ? : Array < "create" | "read" | "update" | "delete" | "list" > ;
        include ? : any[];
        pagination ? : boolean;
        updateMethod ? : "POST" | "PUT" | "PATCH";
        search ? : SearchOptions | SearchOptions[];
        sort ? : SortOptions;
        reloadInstances ? : boolean;
        associations ? : boolean;
        excludeAttributes ? : string[];
        readOnlyAttributes ? : string[];
        associationOptions: any;
        attributes: any;
        projects: any;
        controllers: any;
        create: Controllers$create;
        read: Controllers$read;
        update: Controllers$update;
        delete: Controllers$update;
        list: Controllers$list;
        all: Controllers$all;
        associationsInfo: any;
        use: any;
    }
```

and:

```
declare interface ResourceOptions {
        app ? : Express | Router;
        sequelize ? : Sequelize;
        model: any;
        endpoints ? : string[];
        actions ? : Array < "create" | "read" | "update" | "delete" | "list" > ;
        include ? : any[];
        pagination ? : boolean;
        updateMethod ? : "POST" | "PUT" | "PATCH";
        search ? : SearchOptions | SearchOptions[];
        sort ? : SortOptions;
        reloadInstances ? : boolean;
        associations ? : boolean;
        excludeAttributes ? : string[];
        readOnlyAttributes ? : string[];
    }
```

But flow keeps complaining, specifically about `endpoints ?: string[];`:

```
 • undefined [2] is incompatible with array type [3] in property endpoints.
```

What can I do to make it work?

Comment: I don't think a class can have optional parameters (the `?` after the property name) based on [this example](https://flow.org/try/#0MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1pgPwC5oDsCuAtgEYCmATgNxIC+QA). Not sure if that's leading to the problem but it seems like it will cause an issue.

Comment: This was automatically generated from flowgen from an existing TypeScript definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really an expert on how classes and interface interact in flow, but basically the interface isn't allowing for the possibility of the property exist but being undefined. If you union `void` into the property type, the error will [go away](https://flow.org/try/#0CYUwxgNghgTiAEBLAdgFxDAZlMCBKIAzgPYCuMuA8gA6qLHKHwDeAUPB5xyMsNcSlRMA-PABc8QqhgoA5gG0AuvAA+8AG4DgAbngB6PfADuxGAGtC7LpwM8+AtCPGTpcpboPxgxIsgDkqFYcAL6srKCQsAiRhEwEJOS4SAC21BAgyTxC8PFkFCA0dAxMbNacdvyChMISUjLICoraQfDBQA).